# Toggle a div to calculated position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the code below. I want it to animate a div to a calculated position, but something is not possible or I have made a mistake. Can anyone help please?

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var is_Clicked = false;
      $("#togglebutton").click(function() {
        if (is_Clicked) {
          $('#myToggleDiv').css('float','left');
          $("#myToggleDiv").animate({
            left: '0%'
          });
          is_Clicked = false;
        } else {
           $('#myToggleDiv').css('float','right');
            $("#myToggleDiv").animate({
                $('#myToggleDiv').css('right','calc(100vw - 40px));
          });
          is_Clicked = true;
        }
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br><br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
    });
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#myToggleDiv {
 position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#togglebutton {
  width: 10%;
  height: 40%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 60vw;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1365px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 70vw;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 90vw;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myToggleDiv">

  <input type="button" value="Toggle" id="togglebutton">
  <p id="myText"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The syntax of your `animate()` call is wrong - you need to provide a valid object: http://jsfiddle.net/100pvu95/37/. That being said you have a much bigger issue in that you cannot animate calculated CSS values, so what you are doing will not work, even with correct syntax.

Comment: Why link to an external fiddle when you have fiddle tools **in the question editor**?

Comment: You put **`$('#myToggleDiv').css('right','calc(100vw - 40px));`** inside an **object**?

Comment: Put `$('#myToggleDiv')` in a `var`... D.R.Y!

Comment: @evolutionxbox it help other people to edit and try it.much better than so editor

Comment: @FastSnail [Where possible try to include both a Stack-Snippet and a jsFiddle](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302282/989920).

Comment: also Syntax Error in " 'calc(100vw - 40px)".
You miss ' at the end

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Thanks!! Is it possible to turn the ('right','calc(100vw - 40px)) value into a var and have the toggle animate to that?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `.animate`expects an object. So change you code like this:

```
$("#myToggleDiv").animate({
       'right':'calc(100vw - 40px)'
});
```

Be mindful of putting `'calc(100vw - 40px)'`inside quotes

http://jsfiddle.net/100pvu95/40/

Comment: Thanks! Please see Rory McCrossan's answer. Is it possible to turn the ('right','calc(100vw - 40px)) value into a var and have the toggle animate to that?

Comment: my bad. forgot to notice that. No you can not do so because that's a string. However, you can certainly do this way:
        var something= 5+6;
            $("#myToggleDiv").animate({
        'right': something
          });

http://jsfiddle.net/100pvu95/41/

Comment: Thank you for pushing me in the right direction, Still two problems though. Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849785/keep-toggled-div-in-position

Comment: Seems like it has been answered. If not the case please let me know.