# Keep toggled div in position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the code below to toggle a div to the left and back. I have two problems:

1. I can only toggle the div to its most left position once. Once I
   have toggled back gain, toggling will not move the div again to its
   most left position.
2. I am using `'right': window.innerWidth - 80` to calculate the divs
       left position. Once the div is moved left, I need `'right':
       window.innerWidth - 80` to not keep recalculating the divs position.
       The div needs to stay in place each time its toggled to the left.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var is_Clicked = false;
  $("#togglebutton").click(function() {
    if (is_Clicked) {
      $('#myToggleDiv').css('float', 'left');
      $("#myToggleDiv").animate({
        left: '0%'
      });
      is_Clicked = false;
    } else {
      $('#myToggleDiv').css('float', 'right');
      $("#myToggleDiv").animate({
        'right': window.innerWidth - 80
      });
      is_Clicked = true;
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br><br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#myToggleDiv {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#togglebutton {
  width: 10%;
  height: 40%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: right;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 60vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1365px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 70vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 90vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myToggleDiv">
  <input type="button" value="Toggle" id="togglebutton">
  <p id="myText"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used css animations and percentage calculations so that the container is always 80px at the left of the container irrespective of window resize.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#togglebutton").click(function() {
    var $container = $('#myToggleDiv');
    $container.toggleClass('hide');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br><br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.hide {
  transform: translate(calc(-100% + 80px), 0);
}
#myToggleDiv {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
  transition: transform .3s;
}
#togglebutton {
  width: 10%;
  height: 40%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: right;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 60vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1365px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 70vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 90vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myToggleDiv">
  <input type="button" value="Toggle" id="togglebutton">
  <p id="myText"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Mr Green this works! However, one problem left: I can only toggle left once. After toggling the div back fully in window, I can't toggle left again.

Comment: @Eddy you said it should happen only once right? anyway, I updated the code.

Comment: No, once the user toggles the div fully back in screen I want the user to be able to do the toggling again and again. Out of window - back in window -out of window -back in window, etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 mistakes

1. you need to change both time same **right** size
2. no need to set **float**  css rule

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var is_Clicked = false;
  $("#togglebutton").click(function() {
    if (is_Clicked) {
      // $('#myToggleDiv').css('float', 'left'); <-- NO need 
      $("#myToggleDiv").animate({
        'right': '0%' // <-- modifying right 
      });
      is_Clicked = false;
    } else {
     // $('#myToggleDiv').css('float', 'none'); <-- NO need 
      $("#myToggleDiv").animate({
        'right': window.innerWidth - 80 // <-- modifying right 
      });
      is_Clicked = true;
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br><br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#myToggleDiv {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#togglebutton {
  width: 10%;
  height: 40%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: right;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 60vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1365px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 70vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 90vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myToggleDiv">
  <input type="button" value="Toggle" id="togglebutton">
  <p id="myText"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Armin Thank you, but when the div is toggled fully back into the window, I need it to align left to the window again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `left` & `right` at the same time. You can achieve your results using only `right`.

**DEMO:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var is_Clicked = false;
  $("#togglebutton").click(function() {
    if (is_Clicked) {
      $('#myToggleDiv').css('float', 'left');
      $("#myToggleDiv").animate({
        right: 0
      });
      is_Clicked = false;
    } else {
      $('#myToggleDiv').css('float', 'right');
      $("#myToggleDiv").animate({
        'right': window.innerWidth - 80
      });
      is_Clicked = true;
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br><br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#myToggleDiv {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#togglebutton {
  width: 10%;
  height: 40%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: right;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 60vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1365px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 70vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 90vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myToggleDiv">
  <input type="button" value="Toggle" id="togglebutton">
  <p id="myText"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `'left' : '0%'` please use `'right' : '0%'` in `if` condition. You should have to use either `left` or `right`. Use of both same time will mess here in your case.

Please check below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var is_Clicked = false;
  $("#togglebutton").click(function() {
    if (is_Clicked) {
      $('#myToggleDiv').css('float', 'left');
      $("#myToggleDiv").animate({
        'right': '0%'
      });
      is_Clicked = false;
    } else {
      $('#myToggleDiv').css('float', 'right');
      $("#myToggleDiv").animate({
        'right': window.innerWidth - 80,
      });
      is_Clicked = true;
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br><br>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#myToggleDiv {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#togglebutton {
  width: 10%;
  height: 40%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: right;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 60vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1365px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 70vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 90vw;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #myToggleDiv {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myToggleDiv">
  <input type="button" value="Toggle" id="togglebutton">
  <p id="myText"></p>
</div>
```